# Is it possible to disable (or reduce the volume of) of the AirPods connection sound?

Tags: iphone, audio, airpods

When I put my AirPods in my ears, I can hear a ping sound, indicating a successful connection to my iPhone. My friend who also has AirPods is sensitive to moderately loud sounds, and this sound is too loud for them. Is there a way to reduce the volume of this sound, or disable it?

Comment: Nope! Send a feature request to Apple, they do listen: https://www.apple.com/feedback/airpods.html

Comment: @Harv That page is gone :[

Comment: @Dwa here you go: https://www.apple.com/feedback/airpods/

Comment: @Harv 4 years from now but you responded so quickly lol

Comment: @Dwa does Batman take days off? I THINK NOT.

Answer (score 4):

Try skipping the connect sound by playing something on the phone music or youtube video first before connecting your AirPods to the bluetooth.  I also find the connect sound a bit too loud in my ears. Hope this helps before Apple introduce the feature to adjust the volume of the connect sound. :)

Comment: This works for my AirPods Pro: If I remove them from the case, hold them straight, and cover then inner microphones, then they think they are in the ear, make a sound, and got connected. Then put them in the ear immediately (basically you need to fool the accelerometer and proximity sensor).

Answer (score 2):

No. The system tracks the AirPod volume and the system volume separately so you can keep the phone loud and the AirPods low after they pair, but the connect sound that happens when the AirPods detect they are in your ear canal are set in firmware and not user adjustable.

Unless you can place one in your hand and trigger the connection/proximity sensor this would need a setting to be added to the firmware or software.

Answer (score 0):

Disable automatic detection of ears on your Airpods - you won't hear the chime when putting them in ears : )

Hope it helps !

Also with this trick when taking them out of the case - wait for them to be connected to your device before putting them in ears